# Errors when creating an IBOutlet from UICollectionViewFlowLayout from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet, collectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am trying to set an IBOutlet from my collection view's flow layout property (Which is in a collectionViewController):

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
```

however, when I connect the outlet, I get these 3 errors:

> - Cannot override 'strong' property with 'weak' property
> - Getter for 'collectionViewLayout' with Objective-C selector 'collectionViewLayout' conflicts with getter for
>     'collectionViewLayout' from superclass 'UICollectionViewController'
>     with the same Objective-C selector
> - Property 'collectionViewLayout' with type 'UICollectionViewFlowLayout?' cannot override a property with type
>     'UICollectionViewLayout'

Would someone please explain what this means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`collectionViewLayout` is a property of the `UICollectionViewController` class. Change outlet name to something else.